# check if abstract class exists

Tags: php, class, inheritance, extend

I'm writing a class to check all my dependencies.
One of those dependencies are inherited classes.

```
//File: A.php (For this example, file doesn't exist)
abstract class A{
}

//File: B.php
class B extends A{
}

//File: index.php
$files = scandir("/var/www");

foreach( $files as $class ) {
    // Whole script fails here because file A.php doesn't exist.
    // Need a graceful check to let the developer know a file is missing.
    if( !class_exists($class) ) return false;

    // Do other dependency checks.
}
```

I'm having trouble working out how to test if a parent class exists,
Without the fatal error

> Class 'A' not found

I have error handling for for my common classes.
But for this test case, I need to be able to test for extended classes without knowing their name.

Comment: I don't really get it, you have a class `B` that inherits an unknown and maybe nonexistent class `xxx`, and you want to check if that `xxx` exist ? If I'm right, you can't include the `B` file because it raises an error, so you would have to parse the file searching for `class \w+ extends \w+`-like pattern. BTW, why and how that class could not exist ?

Comment: I had a feeling I should of elaborated more.
This is for my framework, so when I build a new site, I'll run this "test.php" to make sure everything works together.
So as an example, I have class mysql extends db, or app implements basApp.
It's to make sure I have all the required files, before I get in too deep on a project.

Comment: I have thought about your idea of searching the php file.
But was hoping to find an elegant way first.

Comment: I don't think there is, sadly. There is this reflexion thing, but to use it you have to load the class first, and here the loading fails because the parent class doesn't exists... I don't think there is a better way than that, but if there's one I'm really curious about it :)

Comment: Search (which) PHP file for what exactly? Can be be more specific, like pomeh and others, your question is hard to understand.

Comment: @pomeh: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9650542/367456), especially the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **pomeh**'s suggestion, I've created a function to search for "class" and "extends" on the same line. It'll need some optimizing, but it works, so can work on that later.

```
function is_inherited($filePath) {
    $classFileArray = file($filePath, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    foreach($classFileArray as $line) {
        if( strpos($line, "class") === false ) continue;
        if( strpos($line, "extends") === false ) continue;

        $extendName = explode('extends', $line);
        $extendName = explode( ' ', $extendName[1]);
        return $extendName[1];
    }
    return false;
}
```

The library suggested by **hakre** sounds interesting, but overkill I think when a single function will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit like trying to find an answer to the wrong question, and/or reinventing the wheel. PHP will do your checking for you when it throws a fatal error.

If you want to look at it that way, your code actually already works. You get a fatal error, therefore the parent class does not exist, therefore you need to fix your code. Having established that a parent class is missing, what else are you going to do? You still need to fix it.

What I'm trying to say is that if you managed to get rid of the fatal error it does not get you anywhere - your code is still faulty, and likely to crash somewhere further down the line. Sure you could echo 'you have a problem' to the user, but that's what PHP already does.

Comment: I agree and disagree with your answer. You are right if this was for the site in general. But it's as a setup feature. So you can see all the errors at once (Oh there's 3 files missing, wrong file permissions there, extensions not loaded), instead of fixing one missing file, refreshing the page, fixing the next... It's in no way meant for everyday usage. Maybe when adding new modules, to make sure the module is compatible with the installed framework.

Comment: Ok, I get you. If you wanted to avoid regex I suppose you could use some artificial syntax constraint on the framework, so that classes are always named after their files, eg 'A.Abstract.Class.php', 'B.Extends.A.Class.php'. Then if 'B.Extends.A' exists, but 'A.abstract' does not, you know you have a problem, without a fatal error. It's perhaps less ugly than regex, so long as your users play by the rules? I guess you could even code to check that the framework class names are syntactically correct according to your new rules.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I'm going for light weight and elegant though. Trying to have as little rules to follow as possible. As it stands, the only real rule is the directory structure. The function I'm using for now (which I've added as an answer), uses strpos. I don't think I'll find a better solution than custom parsing the file manually first. Since this is just a test page, the function is working well for it's purpose, unless someone comes up with something in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for any class definition that is already in memory, whether abstract or not:

```
abstract class Foo
{
}

$classes = array('Foo', 'Bar');
foreach ($classes as $class) {
    $exists = class_exists($class, FALSE);
    printf("Class %s exists%s.\n", $class, $exists ? '' : ' not');
}
```

Output:

```
Class Foo exists.
Class Bar exists not.
```

See [`class_exists`](http://php.net/class_exists), the manual gives you the details how to control autoloading with that function, it changed between PHP versions.

So that is for "loaded" classes only. If you need to know that for files on disc, you need to do static code analysis and read out the class definitions "on your own", because PHP has not loaded the files so far.

For that, there is a project called [staticReflection](https://github.com/manuelpichler/staticReflection) which will allow you to gather information about classes and their interfaces you only know the file of. It was written by Manuel Pichler who has more information on [his Blog](http://manuel-pichler.de/categories/12-staticReflection).

Comment: yes, but he don't have that `$classes` array, he can't build it. The class name to check is the parent class of a `B` class, and he can't load the `B` class and use reflexion because the parent class might not exists

Comment: That's why there is *static* reflection. Static is before PHP loads it.

Comment: So it does basically what Pomeh suggested?
Parse the php file manually, to check for "class * extends *"

Comment: Yeah but the staticReflection library gives you a nice interface so you don't need to parse manually on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.autoload.php) to load dependencies  at any level of inheritance without errors.

Comment: yes but in his example the `A` file (so the `A` class) doesn't exists so it can't be autoloaded

Comment: @pomeh , if file does not exist, then it is an error. PHP does not include protection against stupidity.

Comment: @teresko the purpose of his tool is to check if the class exists, if the class is valid, in a test/validation configuration, he don't want to use that class but he wants to detect errors, such as the parent class doesn't exists.

Comment: I do use autoload to load all the classes.
It's not stupidity, I'm not the only one using the code, hence my need for a test module.
Things can get over looked, and save sorting through log files, I'm trying to simplify the error checking process.

Comment: loading of classes is not a unit testable code, according to Sebastian Bergmann

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
  $testClass = new ReflectionClass('TestClass');
  var_dump( $testClass->isAbstract() );
```

The first line will throw an exception, if class itself is not found, and second will check, if class is abstract.

Or look up it in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isabstract.php).

If you are looking for making do that all files containing classes are included , then **question title is wrong** and you should read about [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: I think the title is the most literal explanation of what I'm after. I literally want to check if the abstract class exists. Cause once you use class_exists on the child it throws a Fatal warning.
I could probably use a register_shutdown_function hack to display the missing file. But killing the rest of the script doesn't make it a very good product.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!class_exists("A")){
    //do something
    print "Missing class A";
}
```

Comment: As I said, it loads the files from directories, IE: core, drivers..
So I don't know the class name to search for.

Comment: yes, but he know the class name only via the `B` file. And when he include the file, it throws an error because `A` class doesn't exists